# How do I have just the date and not the time displayed along with it in a mySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing records of the date and time each product was purchased. I need to export only the 'date' leaving out the time into another column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not

```
select name, address, DATE(dateofbirth) from myfriends
```

not work? eg, just put Date() work?

Answer (score 0):

use the `DATE()` function.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) is the manual

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the results of a SELECT query?

Something like:

```
select concat(dayofmonth(MyDateTime), month(MyDateTime), year(MyDateTime)) from MyTable;
```

Should work for you.